# Angular: Provide class in a component with all dependencies

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

In Angular (4+) I'm wondering how to provide a injectable class inclusive all dependencies of that class.

**Example:**

DepMaster is a injectable which in turn has dependencies injected, namely:

```
DepServantA
DepServantB
```

If I provide `DepMaster`, I also have to provide all of the dependencies and sub-dependencies. Following does not work:

```
@Component({
    // ...
    providers: [
       DepMaster
    ]
})
```

In order to make it work I have to write

```
@Component({
    // ...
    providers: [
       DepMaster
       DepServant1,
       DepServant2,
    ]
})
```

When providing `DepMaster`, I don't want to bother which dependencies of `DepMaster` are there. I just want to provide `DepMaster` and all its dependencies, whatsoever.

Having to list all dependencies and sub-dependencies would be impossible to maintain. Whenever a sub-dependency changes I would have to update the usages.
In this way the usage would depend on the implementation details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to have a list of dependencies in my master class. Then I can provide this list together with the master class.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyMaster {

   // list of dependencies which have to be provided for this class
   static readonly PROVIDES: any = [
      AuGridBuilder,
      AuTableManager,
      AuTabBuilder,
      ApMenuBuilder
   ].concat(
      AuGridBuilder.PROVIDES,
      AuTableManager.PROVIDES,
      AuTabBuilder.PROVIDES,
      ApMenuBuilder.PROVIDES
   );

   constructor( private gridBuilder: AuGridBuilder,
                private tableManager: AuTableManager,
                private tabBuilder: AuTabBuilder,
                private menuBuilder: ApMenuBuilder )
   {
      // ...
   }
```

This is done in each injectable class.
Then in the module I can provide the master and all it's dependent dependencies which have to be provided, easily:

```
providers: [ MyMaster, MyMaster.PROVIDES ]
```

Comment: PS: This works also if the injectables should be provided within a component.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of requirement you can make separate module for these dependencies and your `DepMaster` like this

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [  ],
    imports: [],
    providers: [
       DepMaster,
       DepServant1,
       DepServant2,]
})
export class DevMasterModule { }
```

and then import this module in your module wherever you want to provide these service. eg

```
 @NgModule({
     declarations: [
            AppComponent
          ],
     imports: [
            BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule, DevMasterModule 
          ],
     providers: [],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
 export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Also to provide within a component? I need to provide it within a component.

Comment: I am not able to get you can you elaborate further

Comment: Importing modules is not possible within @Component() specifier.